# Redirect from Dialog API in Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

When you open a dialog using the office.js Dialog API from your add-in, apparently the page opened has to be from your add-in's domain. It can however immediately redirect to a page in another domain.

How would you recommend carrying out such a redirection?

Is anyone redirecting to another domain from such a dialog? If so how are you doing it and what have been your results?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a reminder that you need to load office.js in order to get access to the parent messaging apis and host page ( Office.context.ui.messageParent )

Answer (score 0):

How you do it depends on the framework you are using. This [ASP.NET MVC sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart/blob/master/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChartWeb/Controllers/AzureADAuthController.cs) does it in a controller with a call to the ASP.NET Redirect method.

This [single page add-in sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Auth0/blob/master/Scripts/popup.js) uses the JavaScript window.location.replace property.